# Problems with /dev/sda

Tags: installation

I have 4 partitions in a drive:

- `HP_TOOLS`
- `SYSTEM`
- `B:` (Reserved for Chromium OS)
- `C:`

I want to install the Chromium OS, if the main hard drive is `/dev/sda`, then what is the name of the file for `B:`?

Note that these partitions are in order as in size from small to big.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45212/discussion-on-question-by-redzaimran0480-problems-with-dev-sda).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the file for drive B:, third partition, would be /dev/sda3. But you should check if that is true in diskpart under Windows or under GParted.

On Windows you could run diskpart and use commands:

```
select disk 0
list part
```

Then you will get numbers of partitions, where partition 1 is /dev/sda1, 2 is /dev/sda2 and so on.

Comment: How do I check it?

Comment: @RedzaImran0480 Updated answer.

Comment: So, if its partition 4, it's /dev/sda4

Comment: Yes, but check the size of the partition for the one you are looking for. And installing Chromium OS there would need to also install GRUB on the MBR with options to run Windows or Chromium.

Comment: How do i install GRUB on the MBR?

Comment: @RedzaImran0480 While installing Chromium OS you should have a chance to do that. If not, you may want to use some Linux runned from USB and then configuring GRUB and installing it by update-grub or update-grub2 command. Search on the Internet how to do that.

Comment: During installation of Chromium OS? How?

Comment: Ask another question for that, the main problem has been solved. Mark the answer.

Comment: It’s actually `sda5`, because it’s in an Extended Partition.

Comment: In the diskpart, the extended partition is labeled 'Partition 0'